# Is there v such that$\|u-v\|=d(u,V)$ with strict convex property

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $U$ be a normed space with a norm $\|.\|$.

How to show that there is at most one element $v\in V$ where $V$ is a subspace of $U$ such that
$$\|u-v\|=d(u,V)$$

iff $ \|u + v\| = \|u\|+ \|v\|$ implies $u=\alpha v$ for some $\alpha>0$, where $u,v\in U$.

....

I tried this
$ \|u - v\| = \|u +(- v)\|=\|u\|+ \|v\|=\|u + v\|$ which shows nonsense things.

Any help???

Comment: In my opinion the title of the question does not match the question itself since the title is about existence and the question on uniqueness. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one direction.

Let $u \in U$ and suppose there exist two points $v_1,v_2 \in V$ with $\|u - v_1\| = \|u - v_2\| = d(u,V)$. We must show $v_1 = v_2$. According to the triangle inequality you have $$\|2u - (v_1 + v_2)\| \le \|u - v_1\| + \|u - v_2\| = 2d(u,V).$$

On the other hand, since $V$ is a subspace $\frac{v_1+v_2}{2} \in V$ so that $$2 d(u,V) \le 2 \left\| u - \frac{v_1+v_2}{2} \right\| = \|2u - (v_1+v_2)\|.$$

It follows that $\|2u - (v_1 + v_2)\| = \|u - v_1\| + \|u - v_2\|$. According to your hypothesis, there exists $\alpha > 0$ with the property that $u - v_1 = \alpha (u - v_2)$.  Thus $(1-\alpha) u = v_1 - \alpha v_2$ so that $(1-\alpha)u \in V$.

If $\alpha \not= 1$ we conclude $u \in V$ too. But this means $d(u,V) = 0$ so that $v_1 = v_2 = u$. If $\alpha = 1$ then $1 - \alpha = 0$ and we again get $v_1 = v_2$. It follows that $v_1 = v_2$ and the closest point is unique.